# Compare 2 tables and extract rows only unique to table 2

Tags: r

I have two matrices with differing row numbers and column numbers. Can I compare row names and extract only the rows in table 2 that are not in table 1?
i.e.

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3], c=letters[4:6])
a3 <- as.matrix(a1)
a4 <- as.matrix (a2)
row.names(a3) <- c("chr1:981994", "chr1:1025751", "chr1:1026919", "chr1:1118414", "chr1:1119410" ) 
row.names(a4) <- c("chr1:1118414", "chr1:1119410", "chr1:1216877")
```

So then compare the two and create a new matrix with
the last row from table 2 as it unique to table 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to compare between the row names

```
a4[!row.names(a4) %in% row.names(a3), , drop=FALSE]
#              a   b   c  
#chr1:1216877 "3" "c" "f"
```

Comment: Thank you so much akrun! I have been trying for about four hours to do this :)

Comment: can you explain what the , , drop=FALSE means??

Comment: @Zoe By default, extract (`[`), have `drop=TRUE`, that means if the output you get is a single row or single column, it will change from data.frame to vector.  To avoid that, we use `drop = FALSE` to preserve the data.frame structure

Comment: This is also conceptually a set operation - `a4[setdiff(rownames(a4),rownames(a3)),,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, but if there are dupe row names, there could be a problem.

Comment: @akrun Is there a way of doing a sequential comparison of two columns? i.e. if column 'a' is the same but column 'b' is different between two data frames then output line to a new data frame?

Comment: @Zoe Could you post that as a new question as it is not very clear from the comments